# TF_OLD_DATA, issue with hector_mapping,

Tags: rviz, hector-mapping, tf

This is my gazebo launch file, and I launch it initially after which i Launch hectormapping in rviz, but it gets tf_old_data error
[Click here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1sZbUjDu2Wkkp32K5M9ZB20ZHboOR8DD-?usp=sharing)

all the files are above

this is my gazebo launch file, sorry i tried for hours brining it inside code tags, but I wasn't able to

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<launch>

  <!-- URDF file for the mobile manipulator -->
  <param name="robot_description" textfile="$(find mobile_manipulator_body)/urdf/mobile_manipulator.urdf" />

  <!-- Gazebo post office environment -->
  <include file="$(find gazebo_ros)/launch/empty_world.launch">
    <arg name="world_name" value="/home/agribot/catkin_ws/src/mobile_manipulator/worlds/postoffice.world"/>
  </include>

  
 
  <!-- Spawn the robot model -->
  <node name="spawn_urdf" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model" args="-param robot_description -urdf -x 0 -y 0 -z 1 -model mobile_manipulator" />
  
  <!-- Load robotic arm controller and parameters -->
  <rosparam command="load" file="$(find mobile_manipulator_body)/config/arm_control.yaml" />
  <node name="arm_controller_spawner" pkg="controller_manager" type="controller_manager" args="spawn arm_controller" respawn="false" output="screen"/>
  
  <!-- Load wheeled base controller and parameters --> 
  <rosparam command="load" file="$(find mobile_manipulator_body)/config/joint_state_controller.yaml" />
  <node name="joint_state_controller_spawner" pkg="controller_manager" type="controller_manager" args="spawn joint_state_controller" respawn="false" output="screen"/>
  <rosparam command="load" file="$(find mobile_manipulator_body)/config/control.yaml" />
  <node name="base_controller_spawner" pkg="controller_manager" type="spawner" args="robot_base_joint_publisher robot_base_velocity_controller"/>
  <node name="robot_state_publisher" pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="robot_state_publisher" respawn="false" output="screen"/>

  <node name="differential_drive_controller_spawner" 
        pkg="controller_manager" type="spawner" output="screen"
        args="diff_drive_controller">
    <rosparam command="load" file="$(find mobile_manipulator_body)/config/diff_drive_controller.yaml"/>
  </node>

 

</launch>
```

this is my hector mapping rviz launch file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<launch>

  <arg name="geotiff_map_file_path" default="$(find hector_geotiff)/maps"/>

  <param name="/use_sim_time" value="false"/>

  <node pkg="rviz" type="rviz" name="rviz"
    args="-d $(find hector_slam_launch)/rviz_cfg/mapping_demo.rviz"/>

 <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="map_odom_broadcaster" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 /map /odom 100" />

  <include file="$(find hector_mapping)/launch/mapping_default.launch"/>

  <include file="$(find hector_geotiff_launch)/launch/geotiff_mapper.launch">
<arg name="trajectory_source_frame_name" value="scanmatcher_frame"/>
<arg name="map_file_path" value="$(arg geotiff_map_file_path)"/>
  </include>

</launch>
```

but in the terminal i get the error as

```
Warning: TF_OLD_DATA ignoring data from the past for frame odom at time 977.265 according to authority unknown_publisher
Possible reasons are listed at http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Errors%20explained
         at line 277 in /tmp/binarydeb/ros-melodic-tf2-0.6.5/src/buffer_core.cpp
Warning: TF_OLD_DATA ignoring data from the past for frame odom at time 977.289 according to authority unknown_publisher
Possible reasons are listed at http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Errors%20explained
         at line 277 in /tmp/binarydeb/ros-melodic-tf2-0.6.5/src/buffer_core.cpp
[ WARN] [1704882542.728729368]: TF_OLD_DATA ignoring data from the past for frame odom at time 977.289 according to authority unknown_publisher
Possible reasons are listed at http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Errors%20explained
Warning: TF_OLD_DATA ignoring data from the past for frame odom at time 977.289 according to authority unknown_publisher
Possible reasons are listed at http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Errors%20explained
         at line 277 in /tmp/binarydeb/ros-melodic-tf2-0.6.5/src/buffer_core.cpp
Warning: TF_OLD_DATA ignoring data from the past for frame odom at time 977.314 according to authority unknown_publisher
Possible reasons are listed at http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Errors%20explained
         at line 277 in /tmp/binarydeb/ros-melodic-tf2-0.6.5/src/buffer_core.cpp
Warning: [ WARN] [1704882542.858803565]: TF_OLD_DATA ignoring data from the past for frame odom at time 977.314 according to authority unknown_publisher
Possible reasons are listed at http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Errors%20explained
TF_OLD_DATA ignoring data from the past for frame odom at time 977.314 according to authority unknown_publisher
Possible reasons are listed at http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Errors%20explained
         at line 277 in /tmp/binarydeb/ros-melodic-tf2-0.6.5/src/buffer_core.cpp
Warning: [ WARN] [1704882542.986922887]: TF_OLD_DATA ignoring data from the past for frame odom at time 977.34 according to authority unknown_publisher
Possible reasons are listed at http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Errors%20explained
Warning: TF_OLD_DATA ignoring data from the past for frame odom at time 977.34 according to authority unknown_publisher
Possible reasons are listed at http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Errors%20explained
         at line 277 in /tmp/binarydeb/ros-melodic-tf2-0.6.5/src/buffer_core.cpp
TF_OLD_DATA ignoring data from the past for frame odom at time 977.34 according to authority unknown_publisher
Possible reasons are listed at http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Errors%20explained
         at line 277 in /tmp/binarydeb/ros-melodic-tf2-0.6.5/src/buffer_core.cpp
^C[hector_geotiff_node-6] killing on exit
[hector_trajectory_server-5] killing on exit
Warning: TF_OLD_DATA ignoring data from the past for frame odom at time 977.366 according to authority unknown_publisher
Possible reasons are listed at http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Errors%20explained
         at line 277 in /tmp/binarydeb/ros-melodic-tf2-0.6.5/src/buffer_core.cpp
[ WARN] [1704882543.140704907]: TF_OLD_DATA ignoring data from the past for frame odom at time 977.366 according to authority unknown_publisher
Possible reasons are listed at http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Errors%20explained
Warning: TF_OLD_DATA ignoring data from the past for frame odom at time 977.366 according to authority unknown_publisher
Possible reasons are listed at http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Errors%20explained
```

and when I move the robot using rqt_robot_steering, it moves in gazebo and also in rviz only for some time after which robot jumps to random location, i Have shared my urdf file along with this,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<robot name="mobile_manipulator">
<!--################################# BASE #####################################-->
  <link name="base_link">
    <inertial>
      <origin
        xyz="0.000001 0.000001 0.05"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <mass
        value="138.0" />
      <inertia
        ixx="2.226045152"
        ixy="-2.53781944357671E-10"
        ixz="0.02193666"
        iyy="4.741831087"
        iyz="2.59578155845563E-12"
        izz="6.106306509" />
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="1.5707963267949 0 3.14" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://mobile_manipulator_body/meshes/robot_base.stl" />
      </geometry>
      <material
        name="">
        <color
          rgba="0.79216 0.81961 0.93333 1" />
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="1.5707963267949 0 3.14" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://mobile_manipulator_body/meshes/robot_base.stl" />
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>

<link name="front_left_wheel">
    <inertial>
      <origin
        xyz="-4.1867E-18 0.0068085 -1.65658661799998E-18"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <mass
        value="2.6578" />
      <inertia
        ixx="0.00856502765719703"
        ixy="1.5074118157338E-19"
        ixz="-4.78150098725052E-19"
        iyy="0.013670640432096"
        iyz="-2.68136447099727E-19"
        izz="0.00856502765719703" />
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="1.5707963267949 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://mobile_manipulator_body/meshes/wheel.stl" />
      </geometry>
      <material
        name="">
        <color
          rgba="0.79216 0.81961 0.93333 1" />
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="1.5707963267949 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://mobile_manipulator_body/meshes/wheel.stl" />
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>

<link name="front_right_wheel">
    <inertial>
      <origin
        xyz="-4.1867E-18 0.0068085 -1.65658661799998E-18"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <mass
        value="2.6578" />
      <inertia
        ixx="0.00856502765719703"
        ixy="1.5074118157338E-19"
        ixz="-4.78150098725052E-19"
        iyy="0.013670640432096"
        iyz="-2.68136447099727E-19"
        izz="0.00856502765719703" />
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="1.5707963267949 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://mobile_manipulator_body/meshes/wheel.stl" />
      </geometry>
      <material
        name="">
        <color
          rgba="0.79216 0.81961 0.93333 1" />
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="1.5707963267949 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://mobile_manipulator_body/meshes/wheel.stl" />
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>

<link name="rear_left_wheel">
    <inertial>
      <origin
        xyz="-4.1867E-18 0.0068085 -1.65658661799998E-18"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <mass
        value="2.6578" />
      <inertia
        ixx="0.00856502765719703"
        ixy="1.5074118157338E-19"
        ixz="-4.78150098725052E-19"
        iyy="0.013670640432096"
        iyz="-2.68136447099727E-19"
        izz="0.00856502765719703" />
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="1.5707963267949 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://mobile_manipulator_body/meshes/wheel.stl" />
      </geometry>
      <material
        name="">
        <color
          rgba="0.79216 0.81961 0.93333 1" />
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="1.5707963267949 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://mobile_manipulator_body/meshes/wheel.stl" />
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>

<link name="rear_right_wheel">
    <inertial>
      <origin
        xyz="-4.1867E-18 0.0068085 -1.65658661799998E-18"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <mass
        value="2.6578" />
      <inertia
        ixx="0.00856502765719703"
        ixy="1.5074118157338E-19"
        ixz="-4.78150098725052E-19"
        iyy="0.013670640432096"
        iyz="-2.68136447099727E-19"
        izz="0.00856502765719703" />
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="1.5707963267949 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://mobile_manipulator_body/meshes/wheel.stl" />
      </geometry>
      <material
        name="">
        <color
          rgba="0.79216 0.81961 0.93333 1" />
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="1.5707963267949 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://mobile_manipulator_body/meshes/wheel.stl" />
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>


<joint name="front_left_wheel_joint" type="continuous">
    <axis xyz="0 1 0"/>
    <parent link ="base_link"/>
    <child link ="front_left_wheel"/>
    <origin rpy ="0 0 0" xyz= "0.220 0.250 0"/>
  </joint>


<joint name="front_right_wheel_joint" type="continuous">
    <axis xyz="0 1 0"/>
    <parent link ="base_link"/>
    <child link ="front_right_wheel"/>
    <origin rpy ="0 0 0" xyz= "0.220 -0.250 0"/>
  </joint>

<joint name="rear_left_wheel_joint" type="continuous">
    <axis xyz="0 1 0"/>
    <parent link ="base_link"/>
    <child link ="rear_left_wheel"/>
    <origin rpy ="0 0 0" xyz= "-0.220 0.250 0"/>
  </joint>

<joint name="rear_right_wheel_joint" type="continuous">
    <axis xyz="0 1 0"/>
    <parent link ="base_link"/>
    <child link ="rear_right_wheel"/>
    <origin rpy ="0 0 0" xyz= "-0.220 -0.250 0"/>
</joint>
<!--############################## ARM ########################################-->

 <link name="arm_base">
    <inertial>
      <origin
        xyz="7.7128E-09 -0.063005 -3.01969999961422E-08"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <mass
        value="1.6004" />
      <inertia
        ixx="0.00552196561445819"
        ixy="7.9550614501301E-10"
        ixz="-1.34378458924839E-09"
        iyy="0.00352397447953875"
        iyz="-1.10071809773382E-08"
        izz="0.00553739792746489" />
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://mobile_manipulator_body/meshes/arm_base.stl" />
      </geometry>
      <material
        name="">
        <color
          rgba="0.79216 0.81961 0.93333 1" />
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://mobile_manipulator_body/meshes/arm_base.stl" />
      </geometry>
    </collision>
</link>

<link
    name="bicep">
    <inertial>
      <origin
        xyz="0.12821 3.5589E-06 0.052492"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <mass
        value="1.1198" />
      <inertia
        ixx="0.0012474"
        ixy="-5.4004E-07"
        ixz="-0.0013148"
        iyy="0.0072923"
        iyz="-1.8586E-07"
        izz="0.0068178" />
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 -1.5708 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://mobile_manipulator_body/meshes/bicep.stl" />
      </geometry>
      <material
        name="">
        <color
          rgba="0.79216 0.81961 0.93333 1" />
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 -1.5708 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://mobile_manipulator_body/meshes/bicep.stl" />
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>


  <link
    name="bottom_wrist">
    <inertial>
      <origin
        xyz="-9.1053E-08 -0.069257 -1.86629999995759E-07"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <mass
        value="0.27721" />
      <inertia
        ixx="0.00104290750143942"
        ixy="4.37155302268076E-09"
        ixz="-2.45049603914627E-09"
        iyy="0.000380518373895034"
        iyz="-7.56009835172156E-09"
        izz="0.00106006525067445" />
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0.13522"
        rpy="3.14 0 1.5708" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://mobile_manipulator_body/meshes/wrist.stl" />
      </geometry>
      <material
        name="">
        <color
          rgba="0.79216 0.81961 0.93333 1" />
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0.13522"
        rpy="3.14 0 1.5708" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://mobile_manipulator_body/meshes/wrist.stl" />
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>

 <link
    name="elbow">
    <inertial>
      <origin
        xyz="-0.11109 1.1476E-08 0.046469"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <mass
        value="0.84845" />
      <inertia
        ixx="0.00079656"
        ixy="-7.8011E-10"
        ixz="0.00053616"
        iyy="0.003576"
        iyz="4.6326E-10"
        izz="0.0033698" />
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin
        xyz="0.0 0.05163 0.20994"
        rpy="0 -1.5708 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://mobile_manipulator_body/meshes/elbow.stl" />
      </geometry>
      <material
        name="">
        <color
          rgba="0.79216 0.81961 0.93333 1" />
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin
        xyz="0.0 0.05163 0.20994"
        rpy="0 -1.5708 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://mobile_manipulator_body/meshes/elbow.stl" />
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>

<link
    name="top_wrist">
    <inertial>
      <origin
        xyz="-9.1053E-08 -0.069257 -1.86629999995759E-07"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <mass
        value="0.27721" />
      <inertia
        ixx="0.00104290750143942"
        ixy="4.37155302268076E-09"
        ixz="-2.45049603914627E-09"
        iyy="0.000380518373895034"
        iyz="-7.56009835172156E-09"
        izz="0.00106006525067445" />
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0.13522"
        rpy="3.14 0 1.5708" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://mobile_manipulator_body/meshes/wrist.stl" />
      </geometry>
      <material
        name="">
        <color
          rgba="0.79216 0.81961 0.93333 1" />
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0.13522"
        rpy="3.14 0 1.5708" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://mobile_manipulator_body/meshes/wrist.stl" />
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>

<joint name="arm_base_joint" type="continuous">
  <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
  <parent link="base_link"/>
  <child link="arm_base"/>
  <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.20 0.0 0.145"/>
</joint>

<joint name="shoulder_joint" type="continuous">
  <axis xyz="0 1 0"/>
  <parent link="arm_base"/>
  <child link="bicep"/>
  <origin rpy="0 0 1.5708" xyz="-0.05166 0.0 0.20271"/>
</joint>

<joint name="bottom_wrist_joint" type="continuous">
  <axis xyz="0 1 0"/>
  <parent link="bicep"/>
  <child link="bottom_wrist"/>
  <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.0 -0.05194 0.269"/>
</joint>

<joint name="elbow_joint" type="continuous">
  <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
  <parent link="bottom_wrist"/>
  <child link="elbow"/>
  <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.0 0 0.13522"/>
</joint>

<joint name="top_wrist_joint" type="continuous">
  <axis xyz="0 1 0"/>
  <parent link="elbow"/>
  <child link="top_wrist"/>
  <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.0 0 0.20994"/>
</joint>

<!--########################## SENSORS ############################################-->

<link name="laser_link">
  <collision>
   <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
   <geometry>
    <box size="0.1 0.1 0.1"/>
   </geometry>
  </collision>
  <visual>
   <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <geometry>
     <box size="0.05 0.05 0.05"/>
    </geometry>
  </visual>
  <inertial>
    <mass value="1e-5" />
    <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <inertia ixx="1e-6" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="1e-6" iyz="0" izz="1e-6" />
  </inertial>
</link>

<joint name="laser_joint" type="fixed">
  <axis xyz="0 1 0" />
  <origin xyz="0.35 0 -0.05" rpy="0 0 0"/>
  <parent link="base_link"/>
  <child link="laser_link"/>
</joint>

<gazebo reference="laser_link">
  <sensor type="ray" name="laser">
    <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
    <visualize>true</visualize>
    <update_rate>40</update_rate>
    <ray>
    <scan>
    <horizontal>
      <samples>720</samples>
      <resolution>1</resolution>
      <min_angle>-3.14159</min_angle>
      <max_angle>3.14159</max_angle>
    </horizontal>
    </scan>
    <range>
    <min>0.10</min>
    <max>30.0</max>
    <resolution>0.01</resolution>
    </range>
    </ray>
    <plugin name="gazebo_ros_head_hokuyo_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_laser.so">
      <topicName>/scan</topicName>
      <frameName>laser_link</frameName>
    </plugin>
  </sensor>
</gazebo>

<link name="imu_link">
  <inertial>
    <mass value="0.001"/>
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
    <inertia ixx="0.0001" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="0.000001" iyz="0" izz="0.0001"/>
  </inertial>
  <visual>
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
    <geometry>
      <box size="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
    </geometry>
  </visual>
  <collision>
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
    <geometry>
      <box size=".001 .001 .001"/>
    </geometry>
  </collision>
</link>

<joint name="imu_joint" type="fixed">
  <axis xyz="1 0 0"/> <!-- 0 1 0 -->
    <origin xyz="-0.350 0 0.115"/>
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="imu_link"/>
</joint>

  <gazebo reference="imu_link">
    <gravity>true</gravity>
    <sensor name="imu_sensor" type="imu">
      <always_on>true</always_on>
      <update_rate>100</update_rate>
      <visualize>true</visualize>
      <topic>__default_topic__</topic>
      <plugin filename="libgazebo_ros_imu_sensor.so" name="imu_plugin">
        <topicName>imu_data</topicName>
        <bodyName>imu_link</bodyName>
        <updateRateHZ>10.0</updateRateHZ>
        <gaussianNoise>0.0</gaussianNoise>
        <xyzOffset>0 0 0</xyzOffset>
        <rpyOffset>0 0 0</rpyOffset>
        <frameName>imu_link</frameName>
        <initialOrientationAsReference>false</initialOrientationAsReference>
      </plugin>
      <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
    </sensor>
  </gazebo>



<!--###############################################################################-->

<!--########################## BASE TRANSMISSIONS ############################################-->
<transmission name="front_left_wheel_trans" type="SimpleTransmission">
  <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
  <actuator name="front_left_wheel_motor">
   <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/VelocityJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
   <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
  </actuator>
  <joint name="front_left_wheel_joint">
   <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/VelocityJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
  </joint>
</transmission>

<transmission name="front_right_wheel_trans" type="SimpleTransmission">
  <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
  <actuator name="front_right_wheel_motor">
   <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/VelocityJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
   <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
  </actuator>
  <joint name="front_right_wheel_joint">
   <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/VelocityJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
  </joint>
</transmission>

<transmission name="rear_left_wheel_trans" type="SimpleTransmission">
  <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
  <actuator name="rear_left_wheel_motor">
   <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/VelocityJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
   <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
  </actuator>
  <joint name="rear_left_wheel_joint">
   <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/VelocityJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
  </joint>
</transmission>

<transmission name="rear_right_wheel_trans" type="SimpleTransmission">
  <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
  <actuator name="rear_right_wheel_motor">
   <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/VelocityJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
   <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
  </actuator>
  <joint name="rear_right_wheel_joint">
   <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/VelocityJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
  </joint>
</transmission>
<!--################################ ARM TRANSIMISSIONS ######################################-->
<transmission name="arm_base_trans" type="SimpleTransmission">
  <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
  <actuator name="arm_base_motor">
   <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/PositionJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
   <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
  </actuator>
  <joint name="arm_base_joint">
   <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/PositionJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
  </joint>
</transmission>

<transmission name="shoulder_trans" type="SimpleTransmission">
  <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
  <actuator name="shoulder_motor">
   <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/PositionJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
   <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
  </actuator>
  <joint name="shoulder_joint">
   <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/PositionJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
  </joint>
</transmission>

<transmission name="bottom_wrist_trans" type="SimpleTransmission">
  <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
  <actuator name="bottom_wrist_motor">
   <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/PositionJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
   <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
  </actuator>
  <joint name="bottom_wrist_joint">
   <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/PositionJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
  </joint>
</transmission>

<transmission name="elbow_trans" type="SimpleTransmission">
  <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
  <actuator name="elbow_motor">
   <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/PositionJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
   <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
  </actuator>
  <joint name="elbow_joint">
   <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/PositionJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
  </joint>
</transmission>

<transmission name="top_wrist_trans" type="SimpleTransmission">
  <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
  <actuator name="top_wrist_motor">
   <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/PositionJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
   <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
  </actuator>
  <joint name="top_wrist_joint">
   <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/PositionJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
  </joint>
</transmission>

<!--######################################################################-->
<gazebo>
    <plugin name="gazebo_ros_control" filename="libgazebo_ros_control.so">
      <robotNamespace>/</robotNamespace>
      <controlPeriod>0.001</controlPeriod>
      <legacyModeNS>false</legacyModeNS>
    </plugin>
  </gazebo>
<!--######################################################################-->
  <gazebo>
    <plugin name="joint_state_publisher" filename="libgazebo_ros_joint_state_publisher.so">
      <jointName>arm_base_joint, shoulder_joint, bottom_wrist_joint, elbow_joint, bottom_wrist_joint</jointName>
      <updateRate>50.0</updateRate>
    </plugin>
  </gazebo>
<!--######################################################################-->
<gazebo>
<plugin name="p3d_base_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_p3d.so">
  <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
  <updateRate>50.0</updateRate>
  <bodyName>base_link</bodyName>
  <topicName>base_truth_odom</topicName>
  <gaussianNoise>0.01</gaussianNoise>
  <frameName>world</frameName>
  <xyzOffsets>0 0 0</xyzOffsets>
  <rpyOffsets>0 0 0</rpyOffsets>
</plugin>
</gazebo>

<!--######################################################################-->
<gazebo reference="front_left_wheel">
 <mu1 value="1.0"/>
 <mu2 value="1.0"/>
 <kp value="10000000.0" />
 <kd value="1.0" />
 <fdir1 value="1 0 0"/>
</gazebo>

<gazebo reference="front_right_wheel">
 <mu1 value="1.0"/>
 <mu2 value="1.0"/>
 <kp value="10000000.0" />
 <kd value="1.0" />
 <fdir1 value="1 0 0"/>
</gazebo>

<gazebo reference="rear_left_wheel">
 <mu1 value="1.0"/>
 <mu2 value="1.0"/>
 <kp value="10000000.0" />
 <kd value="1.0" />
 <fdir1 value="1 0 0"/>
</gazebo>

<gazebo reference="rear_left_wheel">
 <mu1 value="1.0"/>
 <mu2 value="1.0"/>
 <kp value="10000000.0" />
 <kd value="1.0" />
 <fdir1 value="1 0 0"/>
</gazebo>
<!--######################################################################-->

</robot>
```

I am preparing a agribot to autonomously navigate in fields, let me know what more information should I add along with this, so that you can help me? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The TF_OLD_DATA warning in ROS typically indicates a problem with the timing or synchronization of your robot's transform data (TF). Here are a few quick checks and potential solutions:

- **Verify /use_sim_time Setting**: If you're using simulation time in Gazebo, confirm that all nodes are correctly configured to use this setting. This can be done by setting the /use_sim_time parameter to true.
- **Examine TF Broadcasters**: Ensure the TF broadcaster for the odom frame is functioning properly. There could be issues in how the transforms are being published or in the frequency of publication.
- **Review TF Tree**: Use tools like tf view_frames to inspect the TF tree and check for any discrepancies or delays in the transform data.
- **Update Rates**: Verify that the update rates of sensors and other components are correctly configured and not causing delayed data transmission.